# How to fix Admob interstitial ad policy violation: Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content

Tags: java, android, admob

I have received admob policy violation email

LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS:

Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content.

Below is my implementation. Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this

```
private void initShareInterstitial() {
    shareInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    shareInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.share_int));
    shareInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    shareInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            shareInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            new ShareTask().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            shareInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            shareInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
}
```

in OnCreate Method I am using this code on share button onclick action

```
if (shareInterstitialAd.isLoaded()
      && random.nextBoolean()
       && random.nextBoolean()) {
    shareInterstitialAd.show();
 } else {
     new ShareTask().execute();
 }
```

Comment: i think google doesn't allow to put and displaying the ads while share dialog pop-up will opens.

Comment: share dialog opens only after ad is dismissed.

Comment: where is a) the layout and b) screenshots of the layout? without this information, this is quite a theoretical question, which barely could be properly understood - and therefore would only permit vague assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your post codes are not enough to describe the flow to show interstitial ads.
From the limited codes, it is possible that you show App's contents first, then interstitial to overlap the contents. That violates Admob policy. The interstitial has to be shown before the content displayed.
You can refer to their disallowed examples.

[Disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?ref_topic=2745287)